# bootstrap.bundle.min.js not working on Tauri after build for release

Tags: rust, svelte, vite, tauri

i have a problem with my first Tauri application.

I've created a SvelteKit app with the "create tauri app", then i started using bootstrap inside it to have a quick and simple process for building user interface.

While i'm using it in dev mode everything works fine, but as soon as i started building my bundle for deploy the app, i discovered that bootstrap js is not working.

I've tried running the app from console in linux and i receive this message

> Asset `src/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js` not found; fallback to src/lib/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.html

I think that the problem was related to the path and i moved bootstrap bundle from node modules to a folder inside src, but even after this change i continue to experience the same problem. CSS works always fine, but JS is not loaded.

In fact the program appears fine but features like offcanvas are not working.

Same problem appears also in windows, so i started thinking that is related to build procedure when creating a release bundle.

Do i need to specify import commands in tauri json or something else? Thank you very much